# WiFi disconnects from time to time

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, iwlwifi

I have a Dell Latitute 5420 with Xubuntu 22.04.1. I connecto to a dual band WiFi network (2.4/5Ghz).

WiFi disconnects from time to time. Many times it does not reconnect automatically. I did some troubleshooting and this is what I found, using several computers at the time:

- Laptop with Windows 11 does not disconnect when my Dell Latitute 5420 with Xubuntu 22.04.1 disconnects. This happens both in auto band, 2.4ghz band, and 5ghz band.
- Dell XPS15 (older laptop), also with Xubuntu 22.04.1 does not disconnect when my Dell Latitute 5420 with Xubuntu disconnects. This happens both in auto band, 2.4ghz band, and 5ghz band.

This suggests some to me hardware issue.

Here is the syslog output of what I think is the event:

```
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell wpa_supplicant[940]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-5
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171155] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171256] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171259] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004B, valid: 6
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171262] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-66.ucode
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171266] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171269] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A200 | trm_hw_status0
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171272] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171275] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CB01A | branchlink2
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171277] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004C183E | interruptlink1
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171279] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004C183E | interruptlink2
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171281] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000B278 | data1
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171284] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00001000 | data2
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171286] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171288] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x10807465 | beacon time
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171291] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDE4E1E30 | tsf low
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171293] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000038 | tsf hi
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171295] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171297] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x07D1C197 | time gp2
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171300] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171302] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000042 | uCode version major
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171305] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF1C864E0 | uCode version minor
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171307] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000351 | hw version
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171309] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00489004 | board version
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171312] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80CBFC03 | hcmd
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171314] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x24020000 | isr0
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171316] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00400000 | isr1
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171318] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08F00002 | isr2
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171320] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C00008 | isr3
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171323] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171325] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x057E001C | last cmd Id
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171327] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000B278 | wait_event
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171329] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000000B4 | l2p_control
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171331] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00018034 | l2p_duration
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171334] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000F | l2p_mhvalid
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171336] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000000C7 | l2p_addr_match
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171338] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171340] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171343] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00001070 | flow_handler
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171387] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171389] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004B, valid: 7
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171392] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20003463 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171394] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171397] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80455AE6 | umac branchlink2
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171399] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x804631C0 | umac interruptlink1
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171402] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171404] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDE4E1E24 | umac data1
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171406] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x07D1C18A | umac data2
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171408] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDE43B249 | umac data3
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171411] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000042 | umac major
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171413] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF1C864E0 | umac minor
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171415] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x07D1C191 | frame pointer
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171417] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0885DEC | stack pointer
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171419] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0074010D | last host cmd
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171422] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171445] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171447] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM error/state
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171475] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000059EB | IML/ROM data1
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171486] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171511] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171533] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171538] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171560] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00090006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171565] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A482 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171587] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171592] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171614] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171637] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171660] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171686] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171710] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171734] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171900] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171909] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171931] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW error in SYNC CMD SCAN_REQ_UMAC
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171944] CPU: 4 PID: 940 Comm: wpa_supplicant Tainted: G        W         5.15.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171950] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Latitude 5420/0HC01N, BIOS 1.15.1 12/20/2021
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171952] Call Trace:
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171955]  <TASK>
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171959]  show_stack+0x52/0x5c
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171966]  dump_stack_lvl+0x4a/0x63
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171975]  dump_stack+0x10/0x16
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.171981]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd_sync+0x349/0x360 [iwlwifi]
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172015]  ? wait_woken+0x70/0x70
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172021]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd+0xae/0x150 [iwlwifi]
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172050]  iwl_trans_send_cmd+0x84/0x110 [iwlwifi]
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172081]  iwl_mvm_send_cmd+0x38/0x80 [iwlmvm]
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172107]  iwl_mvm_reg_scan_start+0x2ec/0x400 [iwlmvm]
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172141]  iwl_mvm_mac_hw_scan+0x50/0x80 [iwlmvm]
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172161]  drv_hw_scan+0x43/0x130 [mac80211]
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172216]  __ieee80211_start_scan+0x166/0x690 [mac80211]
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172265]  ? __free_pages+0xad/0xc0
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172271]  ieee80211_request_scan+0x30/0x60 [mac80211]
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172320]  ieee80211_scan+0x66/0x100 [mac80211]
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172379]  rdev_scan+0x2a/0xb0 [cfg80211]
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172430]  cfg80211_scan+0xe3/0x120 [cfg80211]
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172473]  nl80211_trigger_scan+0x47e/0x930 [cfg80211]
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172526]  genl_family_rcv_msg_doit+0xe4/0x150
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172533]  genl_rcv_msg+0xe2/0x1f0
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172536]  ? nl80211_send_scan_start+0xb0/0xb0 [cfg80211]
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172586]  ? genl_get_cmd+0xe0/0xe0
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172589]  netlink_rcv_skb+0x53/0x100
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172593]  genl_rcv+0x29/0x40
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172596]  netlink_unicast+0x220/0x340
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172599]  netlink_sendmsg+0x24b/0x4c0
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172603]  sock_sendmsg+0x66/0x70
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172608]  ____sys_sendmsg+0x252/0x290
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172611]  ? import_iovec+0x31/0x40
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172618]  ? sendmsg_copy_msghdr+0x7f/0xa0
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172623]  ___sys_sendmsg+0x81/0xc0
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172628]  ? unix_ioctl+0x168/0x1e0
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172633]  ? __check_object_size.part.0+0x3a/0x150
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172639]  ? sock_do_ioctl+0x42/0x100
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172643]  ? __check_object_size.part.0+0x3a/0x150
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172647]  __sys_sendmsg+0x62/0xc0
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172652]  __x64_sys_sendmsg+0x1d/0x30
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172657]  do_syscall_64+0x59/0xc0
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172662]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x37/0xb0
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172667]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172671]  ? __x64_sys_setsockopt+0x1f/0x30
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172676]  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172679]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x37/0xb0
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172683]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172687]  ? __x64_sys_getsockopt+0x1f/0x30
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172691]  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172694]  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172697]  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172700]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x61/0xcb
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172706] RIP: 0033:0x7f8b34585b17
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172712] Code: 0f 00 f7 d8 64 89 02 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff eb b9 0f 1f 00 f3 0f 1e fa 64 8b 04 25 18 00 00 00 85 c0 75 10 b8 2e 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 51 c3 48 83 ec 28 89 54 24 1c 48 89 74 24 10
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172715] RSP: 002b:00007fff99e79138 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002e
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172720] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000564942aa1ac0 RCX: 00007f8b34585b17
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172723] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007fff99e79170 RDI: 0000000000000006
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172725] RBP: 0000564942aa1da0 R08: 0000000000000004 R09: 0000564942bd4bc0
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172727] R10: 00007fff99e79250 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000564942aa3380
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172729] R13: 00007fff99e79170 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172733]  </TASK>
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172737] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Scan failed! ret -5
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172824] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172827] WARNING: CPU: 5 PID: 64910 at net/mac80211/scan.c:436 __ieee80211_scan_completed+0x342/0x360 [mac80211]
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172895] Modules linked in: ccm rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg snd_hda_codec_hdmi bnep ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_hl ip6_tables ip6t_rt btusb uvcvideo btrtl btbcm videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops btintel videobuf2_v4l2 bluetooth videobuf2_common videodev ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 ecdh_generic xt_LOG mc ecc snd_ctl_led snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nf_log_syslog nft_limit intel_tcc_cooling x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus snd_soc_core xt_limit xt_addrtype snd_compress ac97_bus xt_tcpudp snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel xt_conntrack snd_intel_dspcfg dell_rbtn coretemp snd_intel_sdw_acpi nf_conntrack mei_hdcp snd_hda_codec nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 snd_hda_core nft_compat joydev dell_laptop
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.172995]  snd_hwdep kvm_intel intel_rapl_msr nft_counter binfmt_misc kvm snd_pcm dell_wmi ledtrig_audio i915 crct10dif_pclmul snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event ghash_clmulni_intel snd_rawmidi iwlmvm aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd mac80211 snd_seq nf_tables snd_seq_device ttm libcrc32c nfnetlink intel_cstate dell_smbios input_leds libarc4 drm_kms_helper snd_timer dcdbas serio_raw dell_wmi_sysman firmware_attributes_class iwlwifi dell_wmi_descriptor nls_iso8859_1 wmi_bmof cec snd rc_core processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy mei_me i2c_algo_bit processor_thermal_device processor_thermal_rfim hid_multitouch soundcore mei cfg80211 cros_ec_ishtp fb_sys_fops ucsi_acpi processor_thermal_mbox cros_ec syscopyarea processor_thermal_rapl typec_ucsi sysfillrect intel_rapl_common typec sysimgblt intel_soc_dts_iosf igen6_edac mac_hid int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone intel_hid sparse_keymap int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad acpi_tad sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm ramoops parport
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173116]  reed_solomon pstore_blk pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 usbhid hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_loader intel_ishtp_hid hid_generic nvme rtsx_pci_sdmmc nvme_core crc32_pclmul psmouse e1000e i2c_i801 intel_lpss_pci i2c_smbus intel_lpss rtsx_pci ahci idma64 xhci_pci libahci intel_ish_ipc thunderbolt intel_ishtp vmd xhci_pci_renesas i2c_hid_acpi wmi i2c_hid hid video pinctrl_tigerlake
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173181] CPU: 5 PID: 64910 Comm: kworker/u16:0 Tainted: G        W         5.15.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173188] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Latitude 5420/0HC01N, BIOS 1.15.1 12/20/2021
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173191] Workqueue: phy0 ieee80211_scan_work [mac80211]
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173278] RIP: 0010:__ieee80211_scan_completed+0x342/0x360 [mac80211]
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173354] Code: 0f a3 05 71 8a fc c3 0f 83 d3 fe ff ff 48 8b 05 44 29 0e 00 48 85 c0 74 0c 48 8b 78 08 4c 89 e6 e8 13 27 04 00 e9 b6 fe ff ff <0f> 0b 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f 5d c3 cc cc cc cc 66 66 2e 0f 1f
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173358] RSP: 0018:ffffb0edc0ba7dd8 EFLAGS: 00010246
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173363] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: ffff9c494820bf00
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173367] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff9c49479d8820
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173370] RBP: ffffb0edc0ba7e00 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173372] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff9c49479d8820
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173375] R13: ffff9c49479d9ab8 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000001
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173378] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9c4cbfb40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173382] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173385] CR2: 00007feb4f1c4000 CR3: 00000004556c6005 CR4: 0000000000770ee0
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173389] PKRU: 55555554
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173391] Call Trace:
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173393]  <TASK>
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173397]  ieee80211_scan_work+0x161/0x660 [mac80211]
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173494]  ? finish_task_switch.isra.0+0x7e/0x280
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173504]  process_one_work+0x228/0x3d0
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173510]  worker_thread+0x53/0x420
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173515]  ? process_one_work+0x3d0/0x3d0
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173521]  kthread+0x127/0x150
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173528]  ? set_kthread_struct+0x50/0x50
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173535]  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x30
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173545]  </TASK>
Jan 27 12:22:20 lucho-dell kernel: [249880.173548] ---[ end trace f9de41dca055e0f8 ]---
Jan 27 12:22:21 lucho-dell wpa_supplicant[940]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=DRIVER type=WORLD
Jan 27 12:22:33 lucho-dell wpa_supplicant[940]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-69 noise=9999 txrate=73100
Jan 27 12:25:42 lucho-dell kernel: [250081.392050] kauditd_printk_skb: 15 callbacks suppressed
Jan 27 12:25:42 lucho-dell kernel: [250081.392055] audit: type=1400 audit(1674833142.077:1582): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="connect" profile="libreoffice-oosplash" name="/tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_SingleOfficeIPC_a378c46f207014c8c028212a44a032d6" pid=72189 comm="oosplash" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jan 27 12:25:42 lucho-dell kernel: [250081.392065] audit: type=1400 audit(1674833142.077:1583): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" profile="libreoffice-oosplash" name="/tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_SingleOfficeIPC_a378c46f207014c8c028212a44a032d6" pid=72189 comm="oosplash" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jan 27 12:25:42 lucho-dell kernel: [250081.392071] audit: type=1400 audit(1674833142.077:1584): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" profile="libreoffice-oosplash" name="/tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_SingleOfficeIPC_a378c46f207014c8c028212a44a032d6" pid=72189 comm="oosplash" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jan 27 12:25:42 lucho-dell kernel: [250081.392140] audit: type=1400 audit(1674833142.077:1585): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" profile="libreoffice-oosplash" name="/tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_SingleOfficeIPC_a378c46f207014c8c028212a44a032d6" pid=72189 comm="oosplash" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jan 27 12:25:42 lucho-dell kernel: [250081.392146] audit: type=1400 audit(1674833142.077:1586): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" profile="libreoffice-oosplash" name="/tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_SingleOfficeIPC_a378c46f207014c8c028212a44a032d6" pid=72189 comm="oosplash" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

Here is the network devide info:

```
Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 driver: iwlwifi
IF: wlp0s20f3
```

The log file shows something about `CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-5`, and later on a hardware restart request. Can you see what might be the problem?

Comment: Seems to be a bug: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215635 but my kernel is prior (5.15). This seems to be a workaround: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=254766&p=2

Comment: `This seems to be a workaround` so, did it work?

Comment: @JaromandaX For now it seems so. I'm collecting more data...